# WP/WooCommerce REST API cart/checkout/order

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, api

Since the WordPress Rest API is getting [merged into core](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/34928) and WooCommerce extended their API as well I stared to wonder how it would be possible to build an entire eCommerce website with it.

When you create an independent frontend (no theme - standalone app with node.js e.g) and use the API to get all content how can you manage a checkout process or more important create an order?

The WooCommerce API requires authentication to [work with/create orders](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-an-order). This limits its use to existing customers. A normal install of WordPress + WooCommerce enables every user signed in or not to create an order. Further how would you realize a cart inclusive of checking if a applied coupon is valid etc. ? Payment options and similar infos required for a checkout process even if I had the rest of the necessary information to create an order are not accessible via an API neither...

Any help regarding creating an REST API backed standalone app would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: WooCommerce's API is not well thought-out to say the least. I honestly don't understand what they were thinking when designing the API, since it is also lacking things like an endpoint for calculating delivery costs or returning delivery methods(come on, they started as a plugin for physical items that require shipment - without that feature it's pretty much pointless). At this point, until WooThemes starts thinking better of how to build an API and they actually implement needed features for creating apps, you'd have to create the endpoints code by yourself(or modify existing ones).